# Shadow buttons in the API 22 and 21, how to remove?

Tags: android

The guys tell me how to remove the shadow and the stroke of a button. They did not ask itself, in api versions from 15 to 19, it does not, there is only Android version 5.0 and higher (api 21 and 22). screens attached. Button goes to background color and shade at all in the subject ... help ... I use background drawable xml
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W46Pg.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsK3d.png

Comment: do you mean `android:elevation="0dp"` ?

Comment: try it, but dont help

Comment: <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="TEXT"
                            android:id="@+id/id11"
                            android:background="@drawable/button"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/onclick"
                            />

Comment: well what does `@drawable/button` look like

Comment: -button-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <solid android:color="#FAFAFA"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

            <solid android:color="#FAFAFA"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

            <solid android:color="#FAFAFA" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

Comment: i think its basic android 5 setting for buttons...

Comment: android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" - simple solution

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want material design in your app, then go into your values folder and change your styles.xml

Your AppTheme will need to be changed to have a parent that's not related to material.
If that doesn't work, then the issue is that you're probably testing on 5.0 + phones. So the default will be material. If you don't have a -v21 values folder, make it and then create styles.xml (This takes care of the case when your app runs on an API 21+ device.

In that styles, change your appTheme to any of the pre-lollipop parents. `Theme.Holo.Light` for example

Comment: OMG, Thanks, I'll try it today

Comment: problem, I used the toolbar, and if I change Parent in v21, the toolbar disappears, and the problem is solved with the buttons. as we now return to the toolbar?

Comment: the toolbar is part of the design library I believe. You should still be able to use it if you say something like <android.design.widget.toolbar>
(I'm not at my machine to check)

Comment: android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" - simple solution

Comment: that will create a button without borders. If that's what you wanted, you needed to say so in your question. That is an easy solution I could've told you.

Comment: You know, how can I use this for all app?